# What are examples of efficient, type-inferred languages appropriate for working with multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: ocaml, d, type-inference

I don't care much about garbage collection, if present it should be optional. The language `D` fits the bill but I am exploring other options. Surprising to me, this seems to be a sparsely populated spot among languages. I want something with which I can run things at 80% of the speed of C, if possible.

I also would like the language to have good support for multicores. Not necessarily via threads, but anything that does not involve lots copying. For example GNU's parallel mode for `libstdc++` is a reasonably good abstraction for me, but a little weak at giving pre-baked array primitives (this is not a complaint, it is not its job to give array primitives).

I suspect what I am driving at is a `OCaMl` like language with:

1. good support for multidimensional arrays,
2. no(or optional) garbage collection,
3. parallel programming primitives for array intensive code,
4. convenient C FFI,
5. and with a reasonable chance of running at 80% of C speed.

I am not sure what tags to use so suggestions are welcome. **I also want to make this a wiki, but not sure how to do it**. I have heard of `Felix` but do not know if that would be appropriate here.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're pretty much describing D, especially if you have a long time horizon and are willing to wait for some stuff that's in the works to fully pan out.

1. Good support for multidimensional arrays:  I'm mentoring a [Google Summer of Code project focused on just that](https://github.com/cristicbz/scid).  It's not polished and ready for prime time yet, but it's already usable if you live on the bleeding edge.  It also includes bindings to BLAS and LAPACK and expression templates and evaluators to provide a nice wrapper over these libraries.
2. D's default approach to memory management is garbage collection, but enough low-level facilities exist that you don't have to use it where performance or space efficiency is a high priority.  You have full access to the C standard library and can use C's `malloc` and `free` directly.  The ability to work with untyped blocks of memory also allows custom allocators to be implemented.  Both I and the GSoC student I'm mentoring have been using a region allocator, which will be reviewed soon for inclusion in Phobos (the D standard library).
3. Parallel programming:  See the [std.parallelism](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html) module of the standard library.  It's not geared specifically to array intensive code but it's definitely usable for that purpose.
4. D fully supports the C ABI.  All you have to do is translate the header file and link in a C object file.  There's even a tool called [htod](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/htod.html) that can automate the simple cases.
5. D is currently somewhat slower than C because it hasn't had years of work put into optimization, as the focus has been on features and bug fixes.  However, it's not far behind and almost all of the performance difference can be explained by a somewhat naive garbage collector and lack of aggressive inlining.  If you avoid using the garbage collector in the most performance-critical parts of your code and manually inline a few functions here and there, it should be as fast as C.

Comment: Thanks this is very encouraging indeed. Regarding point 5, if I use gdc wont it use the optimized backend and alleviate some of the speed issues. I would appreciate some pros and cons for doing/not doing that.

Comment: @san:  Yes, but the reference DMD implementation has a somewhat outdated backend.  GDC and LDC, which use the GCC and LLVM backends respectively, aren't as mature.  Furthermore, some optimizations are performed in the front end, which is shared by all three of these compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to SciD. As SciD is still quite malleable may I make a feature request for the support of sparse matrices, if it is not there already.

Comment: @san, that would best made on the SciD issues tracker. Then it can be reviewed and remembered by those actually working on it.

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm a huge fan of both OCaml and D, in regards to existing libraries I have found c++ to be the out and out winner here.  Expression template work cut it's teeth in c++'s manipulation of multidimensional arrays and has been used to create extremely efficient libraries that vastly outperform bare c.  Temporaries may be removed from calculations that you just cannot remove from c code that is generic enough to compose operations.  Loops can be unrolled automatically during translationtime.  And you can use autoparallelisation features out of the box that further drive your use of multicore boxes to new heights.  With c++11's type inference features, you have all of your requested behavior in a mature implementation that will outperform nearly any other language out there.

Now, I'm not saying you can't do the same in D.  You just won't have the maturity of libraries like [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm), [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), or [Blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/).  And you won't have the compiler support that you find with [Intel's Cilk Plus and other Parallel Building Blocks](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-building-blocks/).  Obviously, down the road I have no doubt that this kind of support will be available from the community, but c++ is the only language I have used that offers it today.

I *am* saying that you can't get that with OCaml, at least the standard compiler and library, simply because of the lack of true symmetric multiprocessing.  Something like JoCaml, OC4MC, etc. may provide the necessary parallelisation, but you still lack a deep use of temporary reduction in commonly available matrix libraries.

This is just my experience.  It is much harder yet to get these kinds of optimisations from C#, F#, and that family due to lack of deterministic destruction of temporaries - making expression template techniques much more unwieldy.  The lack of compiletime type inference of templates makes many techniques unreachable.  Of all the languages I have worked with over the years, building tensor and spinor libraries, graph libraries, abstract algebras (represented elements in matrices), etc., c++ still holds the best support for efficiency, now in a much better type deduced environment.

Comment: I hear your C++ advocacy and I use it myself including the libraries you mention, but the question was about type inferred languages, so all what you said though correct does not answer anything about my question. C++'s re-purposing of the auto keyword is no substitute for proper type inference where code hardly ever require explicit typing.

Comment: Well, you have the right to dislike having to type auto or decltype.  It's purely an aesthetic judgement.  But if you believe that it isn't type inference or is less capable than OCaml, you are wrong.  It infers on the same syntactic roles (expression and return) as OCaml, and actually in _more_ situations.  You don't need *. in the c++11 syntax, or any type-specialized identifiers, due to more robust overload.  C++ provides just as powerful type inference as D, and that is an easily provable mathematical claim (in category-theoretic type calculus).

Comment: Its slightly more than just aesthetics, it does improve the signal to noise ratio, improves readability and it is less finger typing. However I was under the impression that C++'s type inference scheme as implemented in the compilers available now is weaker than OCaML's, that function's argument types need to be specified. Any pointers to the contrary would be appreciated.

Comment: @san: Function argument types can be inferred from expressions using decltype, like all expression type inference in c++.  If you have expression inference of types, all roles of inference are possible, whether function signature (return types and arguments), object instantiation, generic specialisation, etc.  The problem people have with c++'s type inference is it's verbosity, that you need to specify the expression at the point of type declaration.  I agree I was wrong to call it "purely aesthetics" - it does sometimes cause duplication of expression.  I just meant it's still full inference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I did not know decltype can do that. Upvoted for the helpful comments. In all examples I have seen, `decltype` had been called on entities that have been already declared before.

Comment: Auto and decltype provide inference? No no no. This is deduction only, allows omitting the names of types which can be calculated from subterms of an expression. Inference calculates types based on usage, that's a huge superset of deduction.

Comment: @Yttrill: It appears that you are using inference to refer to parametric polymorphism created through declaration.  This is orthogonal to type inference, but it is certainly something that can be accomplished in c++ with standard template mechanisms.  Again, the equivalent strength here is easily provable in type theory.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest F#.

- Familiar syntax of **Ocaml**
- [2D array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353794.aspx) support in std library for F#
- **TPL**, **PLINQ** and **Async** support for parallel programming
- CLR based, hence garbage collection (Runs on Microsoft .NET as well as open source Mono)
- **PInvoke** for call native C libraries
- Good performance

Comment: Checkout http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/03/matrix-and-linear-algebra-in-f-part-i-f.html for some example of matlab style F# code. Looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Jay's FIsh provides what you want, except for the C FFI. FIsh is polyadic, not merely polymorphic. It infers the dimensions of arrays. You can write code and test on 1 or 2 dimensions but calculate with 5 or 6. FIsh is a partial evaluator. With the Fortran backend it outperforms C code easily. FIsh code is evaluated entirely on the stack (no heap, let alone garbage collector).

FYI: Felix does not have type inference. It is otherwise suitable, and easily has the best binding to C of any language other than C++. It's intended to provide low level concurrency (share memory multi-threading). Felix can usually outperform C by use of high level optimisations no C compiler could dream of. The author of Felix will provide any modifications necessary to make your code easy to read and write and run faster than C (I'm the author :) Just give me some use cases!

Comment: I had read about FIsh a long time ago and would be very interested. Is it something that is still maintained or developed. And thanks for answering on an old question, very few people do. Learning Felix is definitely on my TODO list